# parse a regular expression with fixed length pattern

Tags: regex, parsing, fixed-width

Hi… i have a problem to parse a regular expression with fixed length pattern…

assuming the following line…

```
       __active__         The node where the mouse pointer is currently located.
```

1. start with WS until position → 7
2. than starting a WORD (everything allowed) sourrounded by → __
3. than filled with WS until position → 26
4. than a TEXT string is following

i want to have…

1. the general match → YES or NO
2. if YES → the WORD "active"
3. if YES → the TEXT "The node where the mouse pointer is currently located."

**update**

my core problem is the the 2'nd WS (after __active__) have a variable length depending of the length of __XXXXX…__ (in this example __active__)

Comment: This is a very basic task for a regular expression. Where are you stuck? (In fact, you can work with simple "substring" calls, since you know all the indexes beforehand.)

Comment: Please show your own attempt.  Might even be nice to know what language we are looking at or the regular expression engine in use as both can have an impact on a  solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

> ^\s+__(.+?)__\s+(.+)$

The first group, i.e. the characters within the first pair of parentheses capture the work active in your example.  The second group will capture the sentence.

The regex assumes it is run on a line, and does not care about the positions.

Comment: this was my first thought also. but this regexp match to much… special the both information "7" and "26" is missing.

Comment: Are you saying that you need position numbers?  In that case you should group the whitespace, and then process the lengths of the groups to arrive that the positions.